# As the sessions work in Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, session

When not working with a framework , to track users by $ _SESSION [ user] = $ name ;.
 For example , if I wanted to get user data such as age , address , etc. , into a SQL query which sought the data associated with that $ _SESSION [ user] and obtained data .
I would like to know how to track user sessions , and also collect data in Symfony2 .
Excuse my bad English , I speak Spanish and use google translator to communicate with you . THANK YOU!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In controller you may use service session

Like this

```
$this->get("session")->set("value", $value);

$value = $this->get("session")->get("value");
```

Comment: Could you explain to me what those two lines , and then , as I do to end the user session . Thank You

Comment: The 1st line is to get a value from the session, the second line is to retrieve the value you have set in the session just before. "value" is a key, not a value. `$this->get("session")->set("name", 'Pablo');` ...